# Accessing an outer class from inside a listener?

Tags: java, this, listener

I have a listener inside Class A, and I want to pass Class A to my Class B inside the listener. Normally I'd just use this, but then I'd get the event that triggered the listener.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`A.this`.

(It is rare that the inner class `this` is useful. Indeed it is relatively common to have bugs where the wrong `this` was used. So it is unfortunate that it is the default. Not about to change after 12 years.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to class A in the constructor for the listener:

```
class_a_obj.addActionLister(new ActionListener(class_a_obj) { ...
```